# Using Jupyter IPython and Cassandra driver

Tags: python, cassandra, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to use ipython notebook with the cassandra python driver. Using command line ipython is completely fine; I am able to establish connection. However, when I use Jupyter IPython notebook with same code, I encounter a connection error.

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
cluster = Cluster( contact_points=['xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'] )
session = cluster.connect()
```

I can run the above 3 lines using both ipython and python via command line. I get errors when executing the code in jupyter ipython notebook:

> WARNING:cassandra.cluster:Failed to create connection pool for new host 10.0.0.7
>
> ...
>
> error: [Errno None] Tried connecting to [('10.0.0.7', 9042)]. Last error: None
>
> WARNING:cassandra.pool:Error attempting to reconnect to 10.0.0.7, scheduling retry in 2.0 seconds: [Errno None] Tried connecting to [('10.0.0.7', 9042)]. Last error: None

(I am using cassandra python driver `pip install cassandra-driver`)

Could it be an ip address or routing issue? The error message mentioned for "new host" is pointing to a local ip address and NOT the ones I use to connect. If that's the case, I wonder why ipython command line vs notebook yields different results, so it has something to do with how notebook handles connections. Does anyone have any insights why this is the case and possibly how I can fix or get around this connection error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connection issue has to do with nodes communicating with internal IP addresses. Came across this [post](https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/forum/#!topic/python-driver-user/7Q1oysXHSV8) which helped clarify the problem.

> "When connecting to the cluster from external client using the the nodes' external IP addresses, these internal IPs gets returned as hosts, which makes the connection pool produce warnings since it can't connect to them."

Still not sure why the behavior is different between command-line and notebook environments, but I got fixed the connection issue by using `WhiteListRoundRobinPolicy` as suggested (explicitly specifying the public ip addresses in the cluster)

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from cassandra.policies import WhiteListRoundRobinPolicy

lbp = WhiteListRoundRobinPolicy(['54.209.226.178', '52.7.220.112'])
cluster = Cluster( contact_points=['54.209.226.178', '52.7.220.112'], load_balancing_policy=lbp )
session = cluster.connect()
```

More on [WhiteListRoundRobinPolicy](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/policies.html#cassandra.policies.WhiteListRoundRobinPolicy)